# FeinCMS: Simple Search

Tags: python, django, feincms

I'm trying to build a simple search for my feinCMS page.
With the help of [this tutorial](http://julienphalip.com/post/2825034077/adding-search-to-a-django-site-in-a-snap), I created a search which searchs through all the page titles:

```
def get_results(query_string, search_fields):
    ''' Returns a query, that is a combination of Q objects. That combination
        aims to search keywords within a model by testing the given search fields.

    '''
    if len(query_string)>1:
        results = []
        query = None # Query to search for every search term        
        terms = normalize_query(query_string)
        for term in terms:
            results += Page.objects.filter(title__contains = term)
        return results
```

But I don't know how I can search within various content types.

Right now I have added `markdowncontent_set = Page.content_type_for(MarkdownContent)` but what do I receive and how can I loop through the contents and check if it contains the `query_sring`?

**Edit:**

Right now my Code looks like this:

```
def get_results(query_string, search_fields):
    ''' Returns a query, that is a combination of Q objects. That combination
        aims to search keywords within a model by testing the given search fields.

    '''
    if len(query_string)>0:
        results = []
        query = None # Query to search for every search term        
        terms = normalize_query(query_string)
        for term in terms:
            results += Page.objects.filter(title__contains = term)
            results += Page.objects.select_related("markdowncontent_set").filter(markdowncontent_set__content__contains = term)
        return list(set(results))
```

Maybe not the best solution but it works.

Comment: fulltext search is better handled with a proper fulltext search engine, like Solr or ElasticSearch. You can use django-haystack as a frontend.

Comment: well, I think this is a little bit too much for my purpose. I just need a really simple search